# “This program might not have installed correctly” in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation

When I try to install any software or execute any .exe file in windows 7 computer, it gives me a notification message saying that

`“This Program might not have installed correctly“`.

Why ? that's virus ? Or my Windows7 is Broken ?
Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Is ti every program or just some?  Did it always do this, or is it new?  Have you tried a System Restore?  Have you scanned for these viruses you suspect?

Comment: Sorry, but *any `.exe`* makes no sense in this context. Windows 7 has certain facilities (shims) to make older installers (NSIS, Inno) behave even though they wouldn't. AFAIK this is often done transparently to the user. If that application was created using one of those tools it is possible that they still don't copy files and thus Windows assumes the installation failed. Still, this would be very much dependent on the applications.

Comment: Oh c'mon?  Really?  The old "I'll comment because I can't answer" advice?  Isn't that getting a bit old since... BBS days?

Comment: At leqt tell us when you started to get this error? If earlier then restore is your friend.

Comment: @Bon Gart: cynicism aside, at least I was pointing out flaws in the question, which you *claimed* I did not (below) and offered one potential reason, but didn't answer before the question became meaningful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to Disable “This program might not have installed correctly” Warning, Right?
Try this tutorial;

Go to the start menu and type “services.msc” in the search box then press enter.

A new window “Services” will be displayed. A lots of services are listed in this window. Search for “Program Compatibility Assistance Service” in the list. Right click on this service and select “Stop“.

Now again right click on “Program Compatibility Assistance Service” and select “Properties“.
A “Program Compatibility Assistance Service Properties” window will appear. Under “General” tab in the “Startup type” section, click on the drop-down menu and select “Disabled“.
Click on “Apply” then “OK“.

Now the Program Compatibility Assistant is disabled. To get effect restart your computer. To check the Program Compatibility Assistant is disable or not open the task manager (Ctrl+shift+Esc) and search for “PcaSvc” service under the service tab. Hopefully, you don’t find this service in the task manager. Finally you have done your job sucessfully.

sc : http://www.techtipsgeek.com/fix-problem-this-program-might-not-have-installed-correctly-windows-7/5866/

Comment: This error message shows some times however softeare instqlled correctly but most time when it appears its xlear thqt installed software has not successfully installed on the system. So I don't think tjat OP wants to disable this he just want to get rid of from thia situation with a reason.

Comment: yeah, that simple steap work :)
after follow this steap by steap, then I restart My PC, that problem can be Handle, Thank's All

Answer (score 1):

When you try to install any software or execute any .exe file which may be not compatible with windows 7 computer, it gives you a notification message saying that “This Program might not have installed correctly“. This feature of windows 7 becomes sometime very useful because you are informed if you have done something wrong when installing any program.

But if this warning message pops up every time you install a program, even you’ve installed the program correctly and the program works very fine, you definitely feel irritating. It would be better to disable this annoying window.

Open the Windows services configuration by typing services.msc in the start menu run box. Locate the Program Compatibility Assistant Service in the window and double-click it to open its properties. A click on the Stop button will stop the service in the current session. Changing the startup type from manual to disabled will prevent that the service is started after system restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Why?  Who knows... Sure.  It could be an infection.  Could be bad memory.  Could be a failing hard drive.  Could be a really messed up installation of Windows.  Could even be that the programs weren't installed correctly.  Impossible to give you a definitive answer though, based on the information you have supplied.

Just being honest.

You want **a** solution?  Perform a factory recovery based on your computer manufacturer's instructions.  If there is nothing wrong with any of your hardware (your Ram is good, hard drive is good, etc.) then this should take care of your issues.

If you want to know if it is an infection, you could always use Anti-Virus tools.  There are multiple different suites out there... and your computer most likely came with one.

You could also bring the computer to a computer repair shop, and pay a professional to take care of the problem.  I mean, this is a complex electronic device that costs as much as a used car... just because it fits on a desk doesn't mean that everyone and their brother should be able to fix it themselves.

Comment: Oh c'mon? Really? The old "do a reinstall" advice? Isn't that getting a bit old ever since Windows 2000?

Comment: Well, the old Reinstall advice fits, when no real information is provided.  It's not like anything was included about the computer other than the Operating system.  It's not like anything was included as to when the problem started.  I could talk about trying to get into the event viewer, if the individual could find it or if it would even run considering their issue.  What's getting old, is hearing complaints like yours, when **YOU** complain about the content of the question as well.

Comment: I still say we need the ability to DOWNVOTE comments, why the one way street, only up votes?

Comment: @Bon Gart: these are two independent problems. And yes, I agree that the question could take improvement, which is why I commented *there*.

Answer (score 0):

Command line way: create a simple .bat file with those lines and execute it

```
@REM Task : Disable "Program Compatibility Assistance Service"
@REM Goal : Prevent random "This program might not have installed correctly" pop-ups
@REM
sc config "PcaSvc" start= disabled
sc stop "PcaSvc"
@pause
```

- What really matters is the couple of SC lines, which disable the service, autostart, and shut it
- @REM are comments
- @pause isn't necessary, but lets you read the output

Personally, I use a bunch of batches and .reg like this one, which I keep in my Google Drive and execute on any new Windows I have to use, which makes things way easier than browsing all menus and MMC.